# Skip first line with goodby CSV

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to remove the column header names from my CSV file import using goodby CSV. I tried using the method [found online](https://github.com/goodby/csv/issues/15) but the table is empty upon executing the script. Example below:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db['server'].';dbname='.$db['database'], $db['user'], $db['password'], array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
));

$config = new LexerConfig();
$lexer = new Lexer($config);
$interpreter = new Interpreter();

$lineNumber = 0;

$interpreter->addObserver(function(array $columns) use (&$lineNumber) {
    $lineNumber += 1;

    if ($lineNumber === 1) {
        return;
    }

    // treat $columns here
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO providers (id, address, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute($columns);
});

$lexer->parse('some.csv', $interpreter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to skip the first line in recent versions of Goodby CSV is to just call `$config->setIgnoreHeaderLine(true);` (added in version 1.1.0 released in November 2013).

---

But what was really wrong with your original code?

Your observer is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (called "closures" in other languages) and has its own [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

What that means for you is that the `$pdo` variable is undefined inside your observer (we say that your closure lacks a reference to `$pdo`). You can include a reference to `$pdo` when creating your closure in this way:

```
...
$interpreter->addObserver(function(array $columns) use (&$lineNumber, $pdo) {
...
```

For performance reasons it is even better if we create `$stmt` only once and reuse it for each row. Then you don't need `$pdo` inside your function at all, but instead need a reference to `$stmt`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO providers (id, address, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$interpreter->addObserver(function(array $columns) use (&$lineNumber, $stmt) {
    $lineNumber += 1;

    if ($lineNumber === 1) {
        return;
    }

    // treat $columns here
    $stmt->execute($columns);
});
```